# How to open a document using aptana command line

Tags: php, command-line, aptana3

Trying to figure out how I can open documents in Aptana. I can cd into the directory but I have tried the following.

```
$open php.ini
$edit php.ini
$aptana php.ini
```

Still nothing works, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you open Aptana first, then File > open > navigate to the file and open it?

Comment: I want to use the terminal as I find it quicker